# How to use Callout for joined points line

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

I want to use `Callout` to make a label of my joining point, instead of using `PlotLabels` like this

```
ListPlot[
  {{{2, 0}, {2, 3}}}, Joined -> True, 
  PlotLabels -> Placed["label", Above]
]
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqd5F.jpg]

It is working for a point, but I can't make it work for a list of points:

```
ListPlot[
  {{0, 0}, Callout[{1, 1}, "Cool label"], {2, 2}}
]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What version are you using? For version 13.0.1, your code ListPlot[ {{0, 0}, Callout[{1, 1}, "Cool label"], {2, 2}}] gives a callout for the 2nd point.

Answer (score 1):

One possible implementation could be:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}};
lbls = {"one", "cool", "hot"};

ListPlot[Callout[First@#, Last@#] & /@ Transpose[{pts, lbls}], 
 Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Or try this variation:

```
ListPlot[Callout[First@#, Last@#, Above] & /@ Transpose[{pts, lbls}], 
 Filling -> Axis,
 Epilog -> {Red, Dashed,
   Line@pts
   }
 ]
```